# Oracle - "ORA-01704: string literal too long" error while creating xmlindex

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create the below xmlindex but getting error "ORA-01704: string literal too long". The error is coming because there are 100s of columns in the xmltable. Any other way to create the xmlindex for this large xmltable?

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_XML ON emp(detail_xml) INDEXTYPE IS XDB.XMLINDEX 
PARAMETERS 
('
  XMLTABLE emp_xml (TABLESPACE general)
    ''/OTC_Dept_Detail''
    COLUMNS     
            Flag  varchar2( 5 ) path ''Flags/NettingFlag'',
            NettingFlag varchar2( 5 ) path ''nettingFlags/NettingFlag'',
            ....
            ....
            ....
            **THERE ARE 100 COLUMNS**
            ....
            ....
            ....
 ') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have exceeded the limits. String literal limit (around 2500 char) and PARAMETERS limit it is 1000 char.

To get around these two limits you have to use clob , and DBMS_XMLINDEX package.

```
declare
 prams_clob clob :='' ;
  PROCEDURE al(p IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB, v VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_lob.append(p, v || chr(13) || chr(10));
  END;
begin 
 dbms_lob.createtemporary(prams_clob, FALSE);
al(prams_clob,q'~XMLTABLE emp_xml ~'); 
al(prams_clob,q'~    '/OTC_Dept_Detail' ~'); 
al(prams_clob,q'~    COLUMNS     ~');  
al(prams_clob,q'~            Flag1  varchar2( 5 ) path 'Flags/NettingFlag', ~'); 
al(prams_clob,q'~            NettingFlag1 varchar2( 5 ) path 'nettingFlags/NettingFlag', ~'); 
al(prams_clob,q'~            Flag2  varchar2( 5 ) path 'Flags/NettingFlag', ~'); 
al(prams_clob,q'~            NettingFlag2 varchar2( 5 ) path 'nettingFlags/NettingFlag', ~'); 
--  **THERE ARE 100 COLUMNS**                        
DBMS_XMLINDEX.REGISTERPARAMETER ( 'IND_PARAMS',prams_clob);
 end;
```

Next create index using registered params

```
 CREATE INDEX IDX_XML ON emp(detail_xml) INDEXTYPE IS XDB.XMLINDEX 
PARAMETERS 
('PARAM IND_PARAMS') ;
```

`q~'a'b'c~' = 'a''b''b'`  - is alternative quoting string literals. Its help to avoid double quotes.